# Why does my UIBarButtonItem have no title?

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to make a UIBarButtonItem with a round border.

```
    let postButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    postButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 30)
    postButton.layer.borderColor = logoColor(0).CGColor
    postButton.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(3.0)
    postButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    postButton.clipsToBounds = true
    postButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 10.0)
    postButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment  = .Center
    postButton.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    postButton.setTitle("post", forState: .Normal)
    postButtonBar = UIBarButtonItem(customView: postButton)

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [ postButtonBar ]
```

I tried this, but the result is a red-outline button with no title.

Comment: You should be using a `UIBarButtonItem()` constructor instead of `UIButton()`

Comment: I've got your button working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work fine if you construct your button correctly:

```
    let postButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    postButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 30)
    postButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    postButton.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(3.0)
    postButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    postButton.clipsToBounds = true
    postButton.setTitle("post", forState: .Normal)
    postButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    postButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "GillSans", size: 10.0)
    postButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
    let postButtonBar = UIBarButtonItem(customView: postButton)
```

I substituted a different font because I don't have your font... Also I added a gray color on highlighting, so that the button appears to respond when tapped.

[image]

Comment: I've updated the code to: ```postButton.setTitle("post", forState: .Normal)```. However, the title still doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use:

```
postButton.setTitle("Post", forState: .Normal)
postButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

I don't know for sure as I don't have your full code in front of me but I think you need to add an action to the button for it to be clickable:

```
postButton.addTarget(self, action: "functionName", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```